# calculation for population vs for group

Tags: statistics, mathematics

When performing statistical calculations like variance, mean squared error, and other equations, the approach differs depending on whether the data represents a sample from a population or the entire population itself. Specifically, the summation is divided by 'n' for population data and by 'n-1' for sample data. I'm curious about how these concepts are implemented in numpy, pandas, and scikit-learn functionalities. I tested the mean_squared_error function from scikit-learn, and it seems to divide by 'n' instead of 'n-1'. Treating a dataset of 300 cars as population data seems unreasonable. Is this difference in treatment between sample and population data not significant? Is it not that important actually and I dove to deep into insights and we generally treat our datasets as populations by convention? Should we be concerned about sample/population measurements in machine learning?